# How to add documentation to an exposed property?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'd like to add documentation to my custom Components. This documentation should be visible in the editor.

It seems already available for standard library components :

[image]

However, it doesn't work for my code:

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MainPlayer : MonoBehaviour {
    // I would like to see this comment in the editor too!
    public string myName;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        Debug.Log("I am alive and my name is " + myName);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Have you tried using MS's documentation standard, it might use that? That would be of the format:
    `///<summary>
    ///Your description
    ///</summary>
    public string myName;`
Where each /// line is its own line, can't do that in a comment

Comment: @T.Kiley Nope, it doesn't work. thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is decorate the field with `Tooltip` attribute.
**Example**:

```
[Tooltip("These are not droids you are looking for...")]
public string myName;
```

Also, if I were you, I'd go `[Header()]` attribute way as it will always show a bolded header above field in Inspector instead of only showing information on hover.

**Docs for Header and other attributes:**
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/HeaderAttribute.html

I'm afraid there is no direct link to the whole section, so you need to navigate in nav on the left to section called *Attributes* which should be active from start.

Comment: Can you please link to some sort of documentation?

Comment: I've added link to `Header` attribute docs but it also leads to whole section for all Inspector attributes. There is no link for whole section so you need to navigate through it with nav on the left.

Comment: @mwilczynsky Thank you very much.